# Docker listening only in port 8080

Tags: linux, ubuntu, docker, virtualization

I tried port 8080:

```
docker run -d --name=myweb1 -p 8080:80 -v /var/www/vhosts/domain/httpdocs/myweb:/var/www/html nginx:1.11-alpine
```

but when I change to 8081 (for example):

```
docker run -d --name=myweb2 -p 8081:80 -v /var/www/vhosts/domain/httpdocs/myweb:/var/www/html nginx:1.11-alpine
```

it doesn't work. I've tried having just one container up or many, it doesn't work anyway.

I installed Docker over Ubuntu 14.04.

UPDATE
First I try to create 2 containers: 1 nginx and 1 apache:

```
docker run -d --name=myweb8080 -p 8080:80 -v /var/www/vhosts/domain/httpdocs/miweb:/var/www/html nginx:1.11-alpine
docker run -d --name=myweb8081 -p 8081:80 -v /var/www/vhosts/domain/httpdocs/miweb:/var/www/html php:apache
```

The first one (nginx in port 8080) works ok. The second one (apache in port 8081) does not work and the error is ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT.

Then I stop the nginx (port 8080) and run another apache container in port 8080:

```
docker run -d --name=myweb8080b -p 8080:80 -v /var/www/vhosts/domain/httpdocs/miweb:/var/www/html php:apache
```

And this one works ok too.

I was looking around tcp and tcp6 but I inspected the containers and all of them have tcp despite of having tcp6 with 'netstat'. Also I found than docker tcp6 implies tcp too.

Any idea?

Comment: Do you get an error or do you just not see anything listening when you list listening ports on your system/look at the output of `docker ps`?

Comment: Everything goes ok and seems to be ok... and the output of netstat for this port is: tcp6       0      0 :::8081                 :::*                    LISTEN

Comment: Hmm, only on tcp6?  not tcp4?

Comment: I think tcp6 is not the cause, the port 8080 is on tcp6 too..

Comment: Right, but is it also on tcp4?  I can't see why it wouldn't listen on tcp4, but depending on how you are trying to connect to it, it would matter.  How are you trying to connect to it.  What's the error you are seeing when you try to connect?

Comment: I load ip in chrome... it throws timeout... I updated the issue, please could you see it, any help is welcome, thanks

Comment: Ok, sorry... it was my local proxy, I didn't realize, I never had a forbidden access before in any other route... It's solved! Thanks anyway

Answer (score 0, accepted):

probably An application use this port. please see below command:

```
netstat -an | grep :8081
```

if you have a result, It's meaning, you have an application that uses this port.

Comment: No output before running the container and this after starting it up: tcp6       0      0 :::8083                 :::*                    LISTEN